# I've failed to please so many people

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

> 1. **I've failed to please** so many people at one time.
> 2. **I failed to please** so many people at one time.

Which of these is correct, and what do these constructions mean?

Comment: Both are correct but mean entirely different things. The first means you weren't able to successfully please many people at one time. The second means you've been failed in order not to please many people at one time.

Comment: **been failed to please** is ungrammatical.  When **fail** has no direct object but a to-infinitive complement (**to fail ... to please...**), it is intransitive, and thus a passive construction is out of the question.  You might construe it as someone failing someone  (transitive **fail** with direct object) in order to please a third party by failing them, but that is not the meaning here.

Comment: I have improved my questions.

Comment: Please check which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Intransitive **fail** means to come up short, to not succeed in doing something, to leave something incomplete or undone. The verb is complemented by a clause headed by a marked infinitive:

> She failed *to water the garden*.
>
> He failed *to arrive at the train station on time*.

There is a transitive **fail** (it takes a direct object), which means

a) to evaluate or grade someone's work or performance as being not good enough, as sub-standard; the person whose work or performance was not good enough is the direct object:

> The teacher failed *the student* for missing the exam.

or

b) to leave something undone with respect to a person, to not meet one's obligations with respect to a person:

> He failed *us* by voting to allow the mining company to pollute the aquifer.

You are using the intransitive form of **fail** in your question. We can form passive constructions only with a *transitive* verbs, and therefore "have been failed" is not correct here.  **BE failed** is a passive form of transitive meaning a):

> The student **was failed** by the teacher for missing the exam.
>
> The student **has been failed** by the teacher for missing the exam.